# Creating an interactive object animation for a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, libraries

I have an idea for a website but I don't know where to start to perform it. I want to create a circle which will be splitted in 2 parts when an user move the cursor on it. Then the user can click one of the two splitted parts and other circle around the first one will appears. I need some special libraries or framework to do it? I discovered this: http://greensock.com/gsap Can it be usefull? I think I want to create an hard animation impossible to reproduce with a simple library or a set of tool. Thank you .

EDIT: This is what I want. A circle in the middle of the screen which will be splitted in two parts (top and bottom) when an user move the mouse on it. Under these two parts there should be two strings, one under the top part, one under the bottom one. When the user click on one string, others circleso should be appear around the first one.

Comment: ["4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! You don't need to use any framework out.
To do that you can use HTML or canvas element;

**Splitting** (HTML)

About the splitting part you should have two inline divs (each one should have CSS `display` property as `inline`) which have the 50% in its width and the 100% height you want in, with CSS `overflow` property as `hidden` (to hide one part from the circle part), then into them must be added one rounded div (`border-radius:100%`) with the full size you want for the circle which will be splited in 2 parts.

*NOTE: the second div (the second part) from the circle must have negative margin with the width of the part, e.g: `margin-left:-50px`, so it will appear correctly.*

Then these 2 divs form an circle, which can be splitted in 2 parts.

**Make each part X and Y movable**

For animating each part from the circle, basically you must set each div as `position:relative` to make their `x` (CSS `left` property) and `y` (CSS `top` property) movable.

**CSS transitions**

You'll need to add CSS transitions to the two divs (the parts from the circle), they are these properties:

(NOTE: you're not obligied to use CSS transitions, but it's more simpler; You can animate them by using timers by the own JavaScript)

```
-webkit-transition:left 0.2s
-o-transition:left 0.2s
-ms-transition:left 0.2s
-moz-transition:left 0.2s
-ms-transition:left 0.2s
transition:left 0.2s
```

You'll unfortanely have to add these `-webkit-` (etc...) to make the transition support longer for many browsers, it depends on the form they interpret the properties. The CSS transition property is called `transition`; In this property you can define which CSS properties will be transitioned.

E.g:

`x=20;x=15`

`20, 18, 16, 15`

I'll not teach so much about the property, but you can have a basic knowledge.
After defining the property to be transitioned you must define the time in SECONDS, it's the velocity of the transition. Milliseconds are after the `.`, but optional.

`0s 0.5s 0.2s 1s 2s`

You can define many properties in one transition by using commas (`,`), like:

`top 0.5s, left 2.5s, background-color 10s, etc...`

(I used extraspaces after commas for good example)

**Modification in JavaScript**

Now you can set the CSS properties from the JavaScript, like so:

`YourElement.style.top="20px"//would set the CSS top property, it's coord. Y`

The events you could use in your script are like these:

`onmouseover, ontouchstart, onclick, onmousedown`

May be defined so in an DOM element or in `window`:

```
YourElement.onmouseover=function(){
    alert("The mouse cursor passed over me!")
};
//adding event using onmouseover property
YourElement.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    alert("The mouse cursor passed over me!")
})
//adding event using addEventListener(name, function)
```

I'm still supposed to update the answer to complete it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm building the HTML part, but I didn't explained a lot about the circle. All it's correct but I want split the top and the bottom part, not the right and the left one. I used 50% on height and 100% on width, so I have an half circle. The problem is the bottom part, because I don't know how to select the bottom height instead of the top one. I tried to rotate the container of the bottom part with transform: rotate(180deg) and it works but now my bottom part is right aligned to the page

Comment: Ok, I managed to create a circle as a sum of top part and bottom part, now I switch to CSS transitions

Comment: @Cricco95 Can you show me it in JsFiddle?

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ndvy3dyp/ Now I need to center it horizontally and vertically. I managed to do the first one with margin: 0 auto; but center it vertically it's so hard

Comment: @Cricco About the circle alignment part it's wrong to do that. You must put them into ONE div which will be the parent of them.

Comment: I used a div to center it vertically but it doesn't work because I think I need to use absolute position while I need the relative one to perform the transitions

Comment: I managed to center both of parts with JS code. Now I need to create a div inside the splitted part, is it possible?

Comment: @Cricco Yeas... you can do it by absolutely moving an text over them with `position:absolute,left,top...` or adding an centered text between the parts which is `display:none` while the circle parts aren't splitted and `display:block` while they're splitted.

Comment: When I try to do it, my div which contain the text stays upper the circle. First of all it is display: none but when i click on the circle which start to split the div should be into the splitted space, while at the moment it goes in the upper part of the circle. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uwxqoyx1/2/